# SolutionPackager Localize command-line argument not producing all language resources files

Tags: localization, powerapps, solution, dataverse

I am having some issues with creating localization resource files for all languages for the description found in my anchor solution. I unable to use the [solution packager /localize command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/compress-extract-solution-file-solutionpackager?view=op-9-1#solutionpackager-command-line-arguments) to create localization resource files for all supported languages `ar-SA bg-BG ca-ES cs-CZ da-DK de-DE el-GR en-US et-EE eu-ES fi-FI fr-FR gl-ES he-IL hi-IN hr-HR hu-HU id-ID it-IT ja-JP kk-KZ ko-KR lt-LT lv-LV ms-MY nb-NO nl-NL pl-PL pt-BR pt-PT ro-RO ru-RU sk-SK sl-SI sr-Cyrl-RS sr-Latn-RS sv-SE th-TH tr-TR uk-UA vi-VN zh-CN zh-HK zh-TW`.

Running this command produces `en-US` resources only. Maybe there is some cli parameter I am missing?

`.\SolutionPackager.exe /action:Extract /zipfile:"C:\Users\Desktop\SolutionAnchor_managed.zip" /folder:solution /localize`

Running this command produces the following output:

```
Localizing 1 components(s)...
Localizing component: SolutionManifest
No solution component files found to localize
Writing string resources...
Removed number of duplicates: 0
WriteResxFile is complete

Managed Extract complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution packager, with the /src /loc flags will create only the languages in the solution currently.

It will also create a template resource file in the base of the resource directory that you can then copy into language specific directories ( that you create ) and localize.

When you rerun with pack and /src /loc, it will repack the languages into the solution.  Subsequent extract operations will now write out all the localized folders for you.